# How to use wget to download Twitter archive

Tags: download, wget, twitter

I already generated the Twitter archive download link on Twitter. But I could not download it via `wget`. It returns the `401 not authentication error`. I have tried to add the username and the password in the command line, but the result still the same. So how to download the Twitter archive via `wget`?

The Twitter archive link is like: https://ton.twitter.com/i/ton/data/archives/****************